# Question about two S parameter curves in ADS (Advance Design System) software

Tags: rf, s-parameters, ads

How do I subtract two S parameter curves and display the result? How do I do this for results from two different models in Advance Design System (ADS) software?

Comment: Are the data for the two models in two different datasets?

Comment: Yes, there are two different files and I want to see the changes between their reflection (s33-s11) and transmission lines (s43-s21).

Comment: It's been a while but, just look for the command/object to load a 2nd dataset. Then write an equation that subtracts s11 from one file from s11 from the other file. Somethingl like `delta_s11 = dataset1.S[1,1] - dataset2.S[1,1]`.